# iOS 7 autolayout subviews misplaced

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, autolayout

in my app i'm placing subviews on the view. when i run the app, the subviews are misplaced. can anybody explain that to me? why is that happening? here is the storyboard layout that i'm expecting to have as the output with it's constraints auto generated by Xcode from the editor (Note: i'm placing my subviews on a UIScrollView):
[image: Storyboard layout]

[image: Constraints]

and here is the output:
[image]

NOTE: i just realised that when i place a subview on the UIView it works fine but when i place it on a scroll view it shift downwards.

Comment: I suspect that you should be aligning with the top guide not the superview.

Comment: thnak you, but how do i do that?

Comment: this may help.  http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/auto-layout-updates-in-ios-7/  But you should be able to drag the constraint in IB to the bottom of the Navigation Item

Comment: are your subviews top aligning to the view's top layout guide?